# What is the difference between those responses?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I am querying a Soap service and the responses differ.
Here´s the Controller code:

```
$clienteSiaconSOAP = new \SoapClient($url);
        $paramClienteSiacon = array(
            'iDDD' => 0,
            'iNumeroTelefone' => 0,
            'iCPF_CNPJ' => $cpfCnpj,
        );
        $responseClienteSiacon = $clienteSiaconSOAP->ROS_ValidarCliente($paramClienteSiacon); // Sei quantas Cotas tem
        $consorciado = $responseClienteSiacon->ValidarCliente->Cliente;
        $consorciado = response()->json($responseClienteSiacon->ValidarCliente->Cliente);
        return view('layouts.index')->withConsorciado($consorciado);
```

Sometimes the response is:

```
{ HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:06:09 GMT [{"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA":"J","CPF-CNPJ":"00635344000177","CODIGO-GRUPO":"07384","NUMERO-SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO-COTA":853,"NOME-CLIENTE":"AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA","NUMERO-CONTRATO":859866,"DESCRICAO-BEM":"HONDA NXR 160 BROS","VALOR-BEM":12975,"NUMERO-TELEFONE":"017 32581859","DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO":"20190423","SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N","DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Normal","FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N000","CODIGO-PLANO-COTA":31,"DATA-ENTREGA":"20180507","DATA-CONTEMPLACAO":"20170622","PERC-TOTAL-PAGO":90.8598,"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE":3.1408,"PERC-QUITACAO":9.1402,"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO":1,"DATA-NASCIMENTO":"","DATA-CANCELAMENTO":"","CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO":"N","SEGMENTO-CADOC":4,"CEP":15115000},{"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA":"J","CPF-CNPJ":"00635344000177","CODIGO-GRUPO":"07384","NUMERO-SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO-COTA":835,"NOME-CLIENTE":"AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA","NUMERO-CONTRATO":861990,"DESCRICAO-BEM":"HONDA CG 160 FAN ESDI","VALOR-BEM":11945,"NUMERO-TELEFONE":"017 32581859","DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO":"20190423","SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N","DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Normal","FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N000","CODIGO-PLANO-COTA":31,"DATA-ENTREGA":"20180507","DATA-CONTEMPLACAO":"20170622","PERC-TOTAL-PAGO":90.7915,"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE":3.1854,"PERC-QUITACAO":9.2085,"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO":1,"DATA-NASCIMENTO":"","DATA-CANCELAMENTO":"","CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO":"N","SEGMENTO-CADOC":4,"CEP":15115000},{"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA":"J","CPF-CNPJ":"00635344000177","CODIGO-GRUPO":"07384","NUMERO-SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO-COTA":209,"NOME-CLIENTE":"AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA","NUMERO-CONTRATO":865778,"DESCRICAO-BEM":"HONDA BIZ 125","VALOR-BEM":12110,"NUMERO-TELEFONE":"017 32581859","DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO":"20190423","SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N","DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Normal","FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N000","CODIGO-PLANO-COTA":24,"DATA-ENTREGA":"20180507","DATA-CONTEMPLACAO":"20171023","PERC-TOTAL-PAGO":88.1946,"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE":4.1003,"PERC-QUITACAO":11.8054,"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO":1,"DATA-NASCIMENTO":"","DATA-CANCELAMENTO":"","CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO":"N","SEGMENTO-CADOC":4,"CEP":15115000},{"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA":"J","CPF-CNPJ":"00635344000177","CODIGO-GRUPO":"07384","NUMERO-SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO-COTA":501,"NOME-CLIENTE":"AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA","NUMERO-CONTRATO":865779,"DESCRICAO-BEM":"HONDA BIZ 125","VALOR-BEM":12110,"NUMERO-TELEFONE":"017 32581859","DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO":"20190423","SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N","DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Normal","FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"N000","CODIGO-PLANO-COTA":24,"DATA-ENTREGA":"20180507","DATA-CONTEMPLACAO":"20170720","PERC-TOTAL-PAGO":90.5994,"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE":3.2696,"PERC-QUITACAO":9.4006,"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO":1,"DATA-NASCIMENTO":"","DATA-CANCELAMENTO":"","CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO":"N","SEGMENTO-CADOC":4,"CEP":15115000}] }
```

when the client has more than one cotas, and is:

```
{ HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:10:55 GMT {"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA":"F","CPF-CNPJ":"53958055672","CODIGO-GRUPO":"04921","NUMERO-SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO-COTA":47,"NOME-CLIENTE":"ROSIMEIRE DA SILVA SOUZA","NUMERO-CONTRATO":339825,"DESCRICAO-BEM":"Pacote de Servi\u00e7os 102","VALOR-BEM":11565,"NUMERO-TELEFONE":"034 32547494","DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO":"20150511","SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Q","DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Quita\u00e7\u00e3o","FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA":"Q000","CODIGO-PLANO-COTA":36,"DATA-ENTREGA":"20130624","DATA-CONTEMPLACAO":"20130613","PERC-TOTAL-PAGO":100,"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE":0,"PERC-QUITACAO":0,"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO":1,"DATA-NASCIMENTO":"19661027","DATA-CANCELAMENTO":"","CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO":"S","SEGMENTO-CADOC":6,"CEP":38406392} }
```

In the first place, I need only the first item to get the `"CODIGO-GRUPO"` and 
`"NUMERO-COTA"` and access another WS to get personal data like address, city, state, etc. to open a home page with rendering.

Witch will be the best way to get that?
Via a VueJS data item and the do a v-for?
Transform this data to some kind of universal accessible data by the blade?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found using each item like {{ $item->{'value'} }}